# Como cambiar de entorno desarrollo a local [codeigniter]

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo una pagina que descargue directo de un Cpanel pero a la hora de ponerla en un hostvirtual me manda a la pagina que esta arriba en la web, la pagina esta basada en codeigniter framework en su version 3.1, en la parte de `application/config/config.php` lo tengo de este modo `$config['base_url'] = "http://sist.sw/";` donde `sist.sw es mi host virtual creado por Laragon`

Answer (score 0):

Esto se define en la primera instrucción de index.php, a través de la constante ENVIROMENT.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Codeigniter está buscando una variable de entorno del servidor llamada CI_ENV y si no la encuentra, considera que su valor es 'development'. Siempre puedes asignar un valor manualmente (`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development', por ejemplo);` o establecerlo en función de la IP o la condición que tú desees, pero lo ideal sería cambiar la variable de entorno del servidor o añadirla en el archivo .htaccess.

Pero eso es sólo la primera parte: en la ruta "application/config/", deberías crear las carpetas 'development' y 'production' y copiar ahí los archivos que tengan configuraciones distintas en función del entorno (presumiblemente config.php y database.php). CI puede cargar archivos distintos en función del entorno. En el config.php de la carpeta development deberás poner `$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/"`, por ejemplo, para que se cargue todo desde tu máquina de desarrollo y en database.php tu configuración de la base de datos local.

Obviamente, tendrás que asegurarte de que en la web del hosting el valor de la constante 'ENVIROMENT' sea ahora 'production' para que todo siga funcionando como antes ahí.

Comment: El detalle es que al querer hacer login me redirige a la paguina de login xD es raro, cambia la URL pero nada mas

Comment: ¿Y el link que te lleva a esa página de login cómo se forma? ¿Quizás se está poniendo la url a fuego en el código y no se está usando base_url()?

Comment: tengo esto `$config['base_url'] = "http://sist.sw/";` asi lo tengo porque es la direccion de mi hosvirtual y la url que me regresa es esta `http://sist.sw/index.php/members/login` pero no me deja entrar a todo lo q me deberia mostrar